# Unable to locate element on web page

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am unable to locate the sign in element on HTTPS.

This code

```
   WebElement signin =driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='mc_mainWrapper']/header/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/a/strong"));
```

causes this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: http://www.moneycontrol.com/

Comment: Try `WebElement signin =driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign in"));`

Comment: Thanks but its still not running and getting error

Comment: Can you copy the entire error stack trace?

Comment: Can paste the entire code and what line are you getting the error.

Comment: please use moneycontol.com website

Comment: FAILED: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Features.Sign_In_Action.Execute(Sign_In_Action.java:29)
 at testCases.Framework_001.main(Framework_001.java:55)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at

Comment: <div class="headTop">
<div class="header-main-wrapper PR clearfix">
<div class="FL">
<div class="clearfix topmenublock">
<div class="FL ML10">
<div class="FR ML10">
<div class="searchBox clearfix FL">
<div class="toplinks1">
<span class="divider"/>
<div class="toplinks1">
<span class="divider"/>
<div class="toplinks1 blp dropdown">
<a class="link1 dropdown-toggle" href="javascript:;" title="Sign in" data-toggle="dropdown">
<strong>Sign in</strong>
</a>
<div class="signinblock dropdown-menu">
</div>

Comment: You need to initialize `driver`

Comment: Thanks...yes due to duplicate initialization of driver I found this error...

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and link text is working.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/santhoshkumar/Softwares/Selenium/drivers/chromedriver2.29");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://www.moneycontrol.com");
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign in")).click();
}
```

The same xpath that you have written also works well for me.